# Subdirectories and Subdomains in host file

Tags: php, file, web, host

I have basic knowledge of **.htaccess** creation. I am pretty sure that if I wanted to make **localhost/test/** be **test.localhost** I would need to do that in there right?

I was just alerted that I would change this in my Hosts file. Can anyone help show me how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That would be your `hosts` file.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for that. Is there any way that you could help me with this?